# Python Regex match multiple and write to file

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have a file with events from multiple Windows servers stored in it, that are non separated (all exports are in one long line, sometimes tabbed, sometimes not).

I've built regex to pull out the information I want to store in a CSV (a total of 20 match groups) but I'm now trying to cycle through many rows in the files and output the relevant information in CSV format. My code is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv
import re

match1 = re.compile('(\D{3}  \d+ \d{2}[:]\d{2}[:]\d{2})')
<snipped for brevity>
match20 = re.compile('(?:Logon Type:  (.+?)   )')

regexes = [match1, match2, match3, match4, match5, match6, match7, match8, match9, match10, match11, match12, match13, match14, match15, match16, match17, match18, match19, match20]

pattern_combined = '|'.join(x.pattern for x in regexes)
print(pattern_combined)
print("End of combined regexes\n\n\n")

with open('Argus.csv', 'r') as fobj:
        with open('Argus1.csv', 'w') as resultFile:
                reader = csv.reader(fobj, delimiter=',')
                for row in reader:
                        output = re.findall(r'pattern_combined',row)
                        print(output)
                        print("End of OUTPUT\n\n\n")
                        out_str = ','.join(output)
                        print(out_str)
                        print("Final output\n\n\n")
                        resultFile.write(out_str)
```

There's a bit of debugging in there as well for my own sanity, trying to see the steps it takes, but I'm failing on making it match (at `print(output)` I just get a null output)

I've tested with a single regex on a single line and can get that to work, but need to expand it to multiple, with each match being exported as a field in a CSV and can't seem to progress.

edit: Sample data added to show the type of extractions required:

```
<13>Mar  8 05:56:00 PHCHBS-TP320161.XX.domain.net MSWinEventLog     4       Security        364388  Thu Mar 08 05:56:00 2018        4634    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing     DOMAINNET\SYS_APM_XXXXXX1     N/A     Success Audit   PHCHBS-TP320161.XX.DOMAIN.net Logoff          An account was logged off.    Subject:   Security ID:  S-1-5-21-2025429265-1383384898-682003330-43805   Account Name:  SYS_APM_XXXXXX1   Account Domain:  DOMAINNET   Logon ID:  0xb1dfe060    Logon Type:   3    <truncated 199 bytes>       364387
```

As you can see, fairly standard Windows event formats, just being pushed into a file via some syslog process that I don't control, sadly!

Comment: We might better be able to assist you if you post a sample text file that you're trying to parse and the intended result.

Comment: Sure, just need to sanitise some hostnames etc and I'll edit it into the question, thanks

Comment: r'pattern_combined' converts literal string 'pattern_combined' to raw string. consider changing `output = re.findall(r'pattern_combined',row)` to convert the value of pattern_combined variable into rawstring

Comment: Try: `output = re.findall(pattern_combined, row)`